# Casper JS Module not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs

I'm using windows with Node JS and Casper JS and I've got the following simple script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: casper.start is not a function
```

Does this mean the casper js module is not loaded?

I'm wondering why? I used npm install -g casperjs as given in the docs

I can see casperjs folder inside my global node_modules folder, but it just doesnt seem to pick it up.

Comment: you've installed `casperjs` but required `casper`

Comment: if I use casperjs I just get "cannot find module"

Comment: Can you check which version of phantomjs and casperjs are installed by using "casperjs --version" and "phantomjs --version". By the way, to check casperjs is working correct you could run "casperjs selfttest".